# How to use joins between two tables with single line spacing?

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image]

below attached file is a query1 in file1 and query2 in file 2, how can we combine two queries one after the other , we can use union but the table was mixed up tottaly? is there any lower join operator?

Comment: sql doesn't have "single line gaps". sql doesn't have "lines". it has records. do you mean  you want a REPORT that shows both tables with some whitespace between them? and since this is msaccess, why did you tag this with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a "Single line gap",
but you can make one more union between table1 and table2 with blank/null or some alike values. code will be something like this:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT'-', '-', '-', '-'
UNION
SELECT E,F,G,H
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although in general I agree with @MarcB's comment on formatting the output, however, this type of formating is actually achievable in sql using unions:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D FROM table1
UNION
  SELECT "", "", "", ""
UNION
  SELECT "E", "F", "G", "H"
UNION
   SELECT E,F,G,H FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need a separator field to avoid the "mix up" and `Union All`:

```
SELECT 1 As Separator,A,B,C,D
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 As Separator,'-', '-', '-', '-'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 As Separator,E,F,G,H
FROM table2
ORDER BY Separator
```